# [PHP ]How To Pass ID to other page?

Tags: php, parameter-passing

I want to pass the id to other page so I can update the data by using the id

I think I've coded it wrong

```
$sql = "insert into hotel (hotel_name, hotel_website, hotel_description, hotel_email, hotel_contact) values ('$hotel_name','$hotel_website','$hotel_desc','$hotel_email','$hotel_contact')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Hotel Information have been Saved");
    </script>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select hotel_id from hotel");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$hotel_id = $row["hotel_id"];
echo '<script>window.location.href="property_add_address.php?id=".$hotel_id."</script>';
```

Comment: You can use header function instead of window.location and check your query as well.
If you want to send last inserted id then you can you $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** No need those select query .After insert query using `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the last inserted id and pass this id to next page .

```
$id=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

**2nd :** Instead of `window.location()` just use `header()` function in php .

```
header('Location:property_add_address.php?id='.$id);
exit();
```

**3rd :** Access the value like this in destination page .

```
  echo $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql = "insert into hotel (hotel_name, hotel_website, hotel_description, hotel_email, hotel_contact) values ('$hotel_name','$hotel_website','$hotel_desc','$hotel_email','$hotel_contact')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$hotel_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Hotel Information have been Saved");
        </script>
    <?php

    echo '<script>window.location.href="property_add_address.php?id=".$hotel_id."</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
echo '<a href="property_add_address.php?id=php echo $hotel_id ?>"';
```